# Existing Database and migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I already have a database (with migration history in __MigrationHistory table) and project, created from zero. I used 'Code First from Database' option and all classes were generated. Now I want to create one more table, I created a class:

```
[Table("Companies")]
public partial class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then I enabled migrations for my context (there are 2 contexts in the project, 2 DB are used):

> Enable-Migrations -ProjectName Infrastructure -ContextTypeName
>   Infrastructure.Asset.AssetContext

it created "Migrations" folder and Configuration.cs file.

Next, I try to add migration:

> Add-Migration -Name Company -ProjectName Infrastructure

It creates migration, but with Create (Drop) for tables, which already exist.

Why? I want to create only differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have access to the original context and migrations? You should continue building your migrations on top of the existing project. If you don't, then you should create a new Code First context, reverse engineer your existing database, then re-enable migrations to start from scratch.

Comment: "reverse engineer your existing database, then re-enable migrations to start from scratch." - how to do it? Clear __MigrationHistory table?

Answer (score 0):

In the package manager console after creating your migration just run the command

> update-database

That should reflect any changes that were made in the migration

Comment: this command can't be executed because such objects are already exist

Comment: Do you have a visual model? Like a .edmx?